# stream / buffer large audiofiles with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to stream music to play it afterwards. 
**This is not a download but a direct stream of mp3 files from the source file to an `<audio>` tag on another page.**

  Things I've tried so far:
1. Use the Web audio API to stream directly from URL (audio.src=url->audio.load()) 
   -->"text/html is not supported".
    -->Adding the MP3 type to the .htaccess file didn't help (yes I alredy tried to move it to the directory where my MP3s are.)
   -->I have to do it manually with PHP, so I can use the content type header.
2. Using JQuery, AJAX and a PHP-file to stream the data from a blob on a MySQL database.
   -->It does not buffer the file, but loads it comletely which takes min. 30 secs.
   --> too slow and maybe a bit too complicated for a simple audio stream where security isn't that important
3. Using JQuery, AJAX and a PHP-file to stream the data from the directory on my Server
   --> same as 2. (besides, that ist isn't that secure anymore)

The code I've used in the .htaccess file is

```
AddType audio/mpeg3 .mp3
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
AddType audio/x-mpeg3 .mp3
```

I have 2 ways to solve my problem, so I have 2 questions
1. How can I tell my server to stream an MP3-File as audio/mpeg3 and not as text/html (in case 1) ?
2. How can I buffer the audio stream (in case 2 or 3) so the visitor hasn't to wait 30+ seconds for it?

---

corrections are welcome.

Comment: You should check the rtmp protocol. This protocol file is not completely downloaded.  is downloaded  as you watch. After downloading the file is executed in the http protocol.

Comment: Are you sure your mp3 files are ok? Why don't you try open them in the browser directly to check it if will be able to play it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, sorry. way 1 DO work. At least if you don't use the FileMatch rules in the .htaccess file to lock every file or directory besides images or pages and forget to include audio files to the allow rule.

*one facepalm is not enough*